# Select COUNT(*) zero if no joined results found

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select all Areas for a given City id.
In addition I am calculating COUNT(*) to see how many Items are existing for each Area.
Since Items are related to Areas via a manyToMany relationship, this JOIN has to go via the appropriate JOIN-table called Item_Area.

Unfortunately I only get Areas who actually have recent items - but I want all areas. Recent items should simple be zero, if none are there. I believe the problem has something to do with the WHERE-condition for the published-date - but I cannot figure out how to make it work properly.

**How can the following query be modified, to select ALL Areas for the given Area.cityId - and simply calculate "recentItems" = 0, for the Areas who don't have recent items (i.e. don't match the restriction on the Item.published field to be within the last 10 days.**

```
SELECT
  `Area`.`id`, `Area`.`name`, COUNT(*) AS `recentItems`
  FROM `Area`
  LEFT JOIN `Item_Area` ON `Area`.`id` = `Item_Area`.`areaId`
  LEFT JOIN `Item` ON `Item`.`id` = `Item_Area`.`itemId`
WHERE
  `Area`.`cityId` = "1" AND
  Item.published > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) GROUP BY `Area`.`id`
ORDER BY `Area`.`name` ASC
```

Comment: Maybe you need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead?

Comment: @tadman: That is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (or two) there.

Answer (score 1):

Move the condition about `Item` from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause. And change the `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(Item.id)`:

```
SELECT
  Area.id, Area.name, COUNT(Item.id) AS recentItems
FROM Area
  LEFT JOIN Item_Area ON Area.id = Item_Area.areaId
  LEFT JOIN Item ON  Item.id = Item_Area.itemId
                 AND Item.published > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
WHERE
  Area.cityId = '1' 
GROUP BY 
  Area.id
ORDER BY 
  Area.name ASC ;
```

Notice that the above will not run under certain (strict) settings because you have `Area.name` in the `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` lists while it isn't in the `GROUP BY` list. This depends on whether `sql_mode` has been set to **[`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)**. So, it may be wiser to change the group by part to:

```
GROUP BY 
  Area.id, Area.name
```

---

You could also use aliases, to make the code more readable (at least for a lot of people):

```
SELECT
  a.id, a.name, COUNT(i.id) AS recentItems
FROM 
    Area AS a
  LEFT JOIN 
    Item_Area AS ia ON a.id = ia.areaId
  LEFT JOIN 
    Item AS i ON  i.id = ia.itemId
              AND i.published > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
WHERE
  a.cityId = '1' 
GROUP BY 
  a.id
ORDER BY 
  a.name ASC ;
```

---

There are at least two more common ways to write this. Grouping first, in a derived table, and then joining:

```
SELECT
  a.id, a.name, COALESCE(g.recentItems, 0) AS recentItems
FROM 
    Area AS a
  LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT 
        ia.areaId, COUNT(*) AS recentItems
      FROM 
          Item_Area AS ia 
        JOIN 
          Item AS i ON  i.id = ia.itemId
      WHERE 
        i.published > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
      GROUP BY
        ia.areaId
    ) AS g ON a.id = g.areaId
WHERE
  a.cityId = '1' 
ORDER BY 
  a.name ASC ;
```

or using an inline subquery:

```
SELECT
  a.id, a.name, 
  COALESCE( 
      ( SELECT 
          COUNT(*)
        FROM 
            Item_Area AS ia 
          JOIN 
            Item AS i ON  i.id = ia.itemId
        WHERE 
          i.published > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
          AND
          a.id = ia.areaId
      ), 0
          ) AS recentItems
FROM 
    Area AS a
WHERE
  a.cityId = '1' 
ORDER BY 
  a.name ASC ;
```

Comment: You can't `SELECT` or `ORDER BY` `Area.name` because it isn't in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: That must have changed - I know you didn't used to be able to, I've had to work around it many times in the past. Oh well, good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The filter condition on Item.published restricts the data to be available for area which has item entry. Since you need the areas without items present as well, you will need to insert the condition Item.published > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) into join.

```
SELECT
  `Area`.`id`, `Area`.`name`, COUNT(1) AS `recentItems`
FROM `Area`
LEFT JOIN `Item_Area` ON `Area`.`id` = `Item_Area`.`areaId`
LEFT JOIN `Item` ON `Item`.`id` = `Item_Area`.`itemId` and 
WHERE
 `Area`.`cityId` = "1" 
 GROUP BY `Area`.`id`
 ORDER BY `Area`.`name` ASC
```